# guardar valor de variable JQUERY

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json',
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(per){
            var film;
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
                    var ul = per.results[i].films[index];
                    $.ajax({
                        url:ul,
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success:function(res){
                            film += "hgagagg";
                            console.log(film);
                        }
                    }); 
                }

                var a = $("<div data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' onclick=\"data2('"+film+"')\" class='col-md-4'>" + per.results[i].name + "</div>");
                $(".row").append(a);
                console.log(per.results[i].name);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

el problema es que cuando envio el parametro film en la funcion Onclic, la variable film tiene el valor del inicio y no la que tiene dentro de la funcion success

Comment: "this.film" es una variable distinta a "film" y solo está en el ámbito de esa función. Prueba a eliminar el "this." para que te setee la variable original.

Comment: ya lo hice y sigue igual

Comment: Ah vale, no habia visto que era una llamda Ajax. Seguramente sea porque se está generando el código de `var a` antes de que la llamada ajax que haces dentro del for sea respondida y, por tanto, tiene el valor antiguo.

Comment: sii es verdad, entonces siempre se va quedar con el antiguo

Comment: Si, lo que puedes hacer es, o bien generar el código en la respuesta ajax o, generarlo al principio del todo (antes del for por ejemplo) y cuando llegue la llamada ajax simplemente sustituir el contenido del onclick con la llamada a la funcion usando el nuevo valor.

Comment: seria antes del primer for o del segundo?

Answer (score 2):

Una solución sencilla es tener un contador de respuestas. Cuando el contador llegue a 18, creas el div:

```
const ITERACIONES_1=6;
const ITERACIONES_2=3;
let helper= {
  film:'',
  counter:0,
  method: function (res) {
    this.film += 'loquesea';
    this.counter++;
    if (this.counter == (ITERACIONES_1 * ITERACIONES_2) {
      var a = $("<div data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' " + 
        "onclick=\"data2('"+this.film+"')\" class='col-md-4'>" +
        per.results[i].name + "</div>");
      $(".row").append(a);
      console.log(per.results[i].name);
    }
  }
};

$.ajax({
        url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json',
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(per){
            var film;
            for (var i = 0; i < ITERACIONES_1; i++) {
                for (var index = 0; index < ITERACIONES_2; index++) {
                    var ul = per.results[i].films[index];
                    $.ajax({
                        url:ul,
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success:function(res){
                            helper.method(res);
                        }
                    }); 
                } 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: me sigue mostrando undefined,

Comment: Editado, había una errata